# Corona sdk app to put text in a video

Tags: android, ios, sdk, coronasdk

Is it possible to create an app in corona to put some text in a video and save that new video with the text included?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in Corona SDK. It might be possible with Corona Enterprise.